# Floating ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

The `ItemsControl` I need must have [this appearance](http://lms.bigbrain.am/YIKOU):

[image]

For `ItemsPanel` I have set a `StackPanel` with a horizontal orientation.

```
<Style TargetType="local:ParameterItemContainer">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ParameterItemContainer">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`ParameterItemContainer` derives from `ItemsControl`.

Don't know how to implement the template correctly to get the same appearance as my screenshot, or do I have to override a function to set the correct layout?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `WrapPanel` with `Orientation="Vertical"`, and giving it a height of whatever 6x items would be?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an answer to my question.

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an Answer below :) I wasn't exactly sure if that was what you were looking for based on your question title, which is why I posted that as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `"Floating ItemsControl"`, however if you're only looking to display rows of 6 items at a time in an `ItemsControl` you can set the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `WrapPanel` with `Orientation="Vertical"`, and give it a Height of whatever 6x items would be.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="300" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

This will have WPF drawing items vertically until it hits the height limit, then it will wrap to a new column horizontally to continue drawing items.